Why is Duty cycle for CC LED driver voltage specific, when Output voltage has a compliant range?
Commercial CC drivers usually mention "x-yV output" range which means that the output voltage has a compliance range where CC operation will be maintained in constant current mode. But then how does one use the calculations in a typical led driver datasheet to design around this compliance range?
The first thing most application information in datasheets walk you through is the Duty cycle. For reference will use TPS92691 (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92691-q1.pdf?ts=1713767756714&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS92691-Q1). There's formulas for D, Dmax and Dmin. As seen Dmax is used in inductor selection, output and input capacitor selection, I limit current resistor setting etc. Calculating Dmax is pretty straightforward as the Vo can be set to the maximum compliance output voltage required.
The calculation for D doesn't quite make sense for a compliant output voltage range. It's used in the calculation for feedback compensation parameters like zero frequency and dc gain. What am I supposed to do here?

Just so that we're looking at the same thing, are you talking about Section 8.2.1.2.1?

For the compensation network, D is the actual duty cycle of the device hooked up to a specific load. If you don't know the load, you aren't going to be able to tune it exactly, so pick a value in the middle. This probably only matters if you're going to use the PWM feature anyway since otherwise the impulse response of the driver doesn't need to be carefully tuned to run at steady state.

@Colin yup that's the section that i'm talking about...do you just take a avg for the typical Vout then?

@user1850479 Ah, I see, so it was the duty cycle for the load - honestly how did you figure that out? Wait what...isn't the compensation network used  to minimize current ripple on the LED, how does the use of the PWM feature fit into this?

@user1850479 I see mention of slope compensation used when D=Dmax for the PWM. Ig, that doesn't quite clarify things.

The ripple is set by the output capacitor, not the compensation network.  8.1.3 lets you pick the ripple you want and then solve for the capacitor that achieves it.  The compensation network tunes the control loop's bandwidth and impulse response, but if you're only interested in steady state performance then anything that doesn't oscillate will work and you can probably just use the example values or something close to them.

@user1850479 That was my misunderstanding, makes sense. Although, I am interested in pulse performance. The controller will be used to strobe various led strip. In that case, how would I approach this?

I've never tried adjusting compensation on a converter before, so besides working through the transfer function and deriving the step response you want, I'm not sure what your options would be.

@user1850479 Ok, looking at it through another angle, how do you design a controller FOR a compliant range of output voltages
